# Prove that every subsequence of a summable sequence with non-negative terms is summable.

Tags: real-analysis

I was currently trying to prove the following statement:

"Prove that every subsequence of a summable sequence with non-negative terms is summable"

I wanted to use the Convergence Criterion for Monotone Sequences to prove this statement. Since the terms of the summable sequence are non-negative, we also know that the terms of the subsequence are non-negative. Therefore, we know that the sequence of partial sums of the subsequence is increasing. Now I am struggling to show that the subsequence is bounded from above.

Can I simply say that the sequence of partial sums of the subsequence is in fact a subsequence of the partial sums of the sequence? And if so why?

I was thinking about using the following theorems:

- Every convergent sequence is bounded.
- Every subsequence of a convergent sequence is convergent and converges to the limit of the sequence.

I was hoping somebody could help me with proving this statement.

Comment: It's not quite true that a partial sum of a subsequence must be a partial sum of the whole sequence. (Consider $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}$ for example, with the subsequence consisting of all terms except the first: every partial sum of the original series is at least $1$, while every partial sum of the subsequence series is less than $1$.) However the overall strategy is a good one. Can you think of some other quantity that would serve as an upper bound for every partial sum of every subsequence?

Comment: I was thinking about using the following ingredients. I know that the sequence converges to 0, since it is summable and I know that the partial sum of the sequence is convergent. However I do not see how I could link them to an upper bound. This is my first calculus, so sorry for my slow understanding.

Comment: I was thinking since every sequence is non-negative that maybe the limit of the sequence of partial sums of the sequence forms an upper bound for the sequence of partial sums of the subsequence. If so how would you write this down properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply say that the partial sums of the subsequence is a subsequence of the partial sums of the sequence. Consider the sum of $a_n=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

$$1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

Thus, if $b_n$ is any subsequence of $a_n$ without $a_1$ we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^N b_n<\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

which is less than any partial sum of $a_n$. What you can say though is

$$\sum_{k=1}^N a_{n_k}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n_N} a_{n}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n}=L<\infty$$

---

EDIT: With more explanation

$$\sum_{k=1}^N a_{n_k}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n_N} a_{n}$$

This is true since the sum on the left is the partial sums of the subsequence. Note that the sum ends at the subsequence term $a_{n_N}$, which has index $n_N$. The sum on the right is the partial sums of every term in the sequence with index less than $n_N$.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n_N} a_{n}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_{n}=L$$

Here, the sum on the left is the finite sum up to the $n_N$ term. The sum on the right is the infinite sum. By assumption, the infinite sum converges.

---

Since $\sum_{k=1}^N a_{n_k}$ is an increasing sequence in $N$ and bounded above, it must have a limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do not completely follow the line that includes the three sums, could you enlighten what exactly happens there?

Comment: This makes so much sense, thank you so much! I have approved the answer.